# OTRS Send e-mails after creating ticket via REST-API

Tags: rest, otrs

We are creating OTRS-Tickets using the OTRS REST-Interface. 
Creating tickets works fine. However no e-mails are sent after the ticket has been created.
The OTRS log shows the message:
    [Kernel::System::Ticket::Event::NotificationEvent::_SendNotificationToRecipients] Send no customer notification because no customer is set!

So I think OTRS is trying to notify the recipients but fails due to missing 'customer'
But how do I set the 'customer'? There is no 'customer'-field in the OTRS-REST interface.
Ticket::CustomerUser, and Ticket::CustomerId are set

Are there other field we have to set in order that the OTRS-verver finds the 'customer'?
Do we have to configure the Notification Management? And how?

Answer (score 1):

The field you need to set is `CustomerUserID` - that's what the whole customer information depends on.

In the [documentation](https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/6.0/en/html/genericinterface.html#id-1.6.12.10.7.4) you can find some sample code for a REST-Requester that features this response example:

```
{
  "Ticket": [
    {
      "Age": 777,
      "PriorityID": 3,
      "ServiceID": "",
      [...]
      "Title": "REST Create Test",
      "CreateBy": 2,
      "TicketID": 1686,
      "ArchiveFlag": "n",
      "Lock": "unlock",
      "CreateTimeUnix": 1404173292,
      "SLAID": "",
      "CustomerUserID": "customer"
    }
  ]
}
```

I excluded some of the fields for brevity, but you can use the documentation as a reference for the field names.

Comment: CustomerUserID is not a field used in TicketCreate and thus ignored!
CustomerUserID is used for example in TicketSearch.

But we found the solution :-)
We had to set CustomerUser correctly. The format of the CustomerUser might depend on the OTRS configuration. It took us a long series of trial and error ...